# What does it mean for folly::Synchronized object to be const?

Tags: c++, synchronization, locking, folly

I want to write some utility functions that operate on `Synchronized<T>` objects.  I could write 2 versions one for const and one for non-const but that seems silly.  Alternatively I could write 1 version just for const.  I'm not sure if there's any downside to this because it seems like you can still modify the "locked" object via `Synchronized::wlock` method.

[folly::Synchronized](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/docs/Synchronized.md) allows calling `wlock` (ie lock exclusively in write mode) on both a `const Synchronized` and non-const `Synchronized` object -- [link](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/a9a982428c495fe91b0f8f9dd1486219b0d76dbc/folly/Synchronized.h#L196-L199).

However they return different output types.  Is there any difference between `LockedPtr` and `ConstWLockedPtr`?  In particular I'm interested in differences in functionality & in particular any lack of functionality with `ConstWLockedPtr`.

Comment: Why is `folly:Synchronized` speical? If it isnt broken then it should be like with other types too: You don't need to call a non-const method, then it can be `const`, otherwise it needs to be non-const.

Comment: Since you already found the source code, why don't you look at those two return types? https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/a9a982428c495fe91b0f8f9dd1486219b0d76dbc/folly/Synchronized.h#L168

Comment: the `wlock` overload that is const does not actually grant you write access. https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/56dc2459f45159370cfc2e628c6172125d906917/folly/Synchronized.h (line 197)

Comment: @tkausl I understand that the types are different but what I'm interested in is any difference in functionality.

Comment: I think you will understand when you try and see what happens

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that they are __not__ different. These two are aliases to the exact same class, the only difference is the held item being `const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wlock` *does not compile* when used on a `const folly::Synchronized<T>&`.  So you must a mutable reference to call `wlock`.  For `rlock` you can use mutable or const; it'll just implicitly convert to `const`.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding a bit more supporting detail.